# How to fix a "not contained in global namespace error"?

Tags: c++, macos, cmake

While trying to run a makefile that cmake generated I get the following errors. I am not too sure how to go about fixing it so any advice would be very appreciated. Thanks!

```
Scanning dependencies of target FSOPhantom
[ 12%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/FSOPhantom.dir/FSOPhantom.cc.o
In file included from /Users/Downloads/FSO/FSOPhantom/FSOPhantom.cc:31:
In file included from /Users/Downloads/FSO/FSOPhantom/include/FSODetectorConstruction.hh:34:
In file included from /usr/local/include/Geant4/G4VUserDetectorConstruction.hh:38:
In file included from /usr/local/include/Geant4/globals.hh:48:
In file included from /usr/local/include/Geant4/G4ios.hh:38:
In file included from /usr/local/include/Geant4/G4Types.hh:71:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/complex:245:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cmath:317:9: error: 
      no member named 'signbit' in the global namespace
using ::signbit;
      ~~^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cmath:318:9: error: 
      no member named 'fpclassify' in the global namespace
using ::fpclassify;
      ~~^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cmath:319:9: error: 
      no member named 'isfinite' in the global namespace; did you mean 'finite'?
using ::isfinite;
      ~~^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.
sdk/usr/include/math.h:749:12: note: 
      'finite' declared here
extern int finite(double)
           ^
```

Comment: If you are using CMake it is unlikely there is a problem with the Makefile. Please provide the Cmake file and some more details about the project structure.

Comment: All of these functions were introduced in C99 / C++11. Perhaps you have to add a compiler switch indicating to use the new language features, or perhaps you need to upgrade your compiler?

Comment: It's not the makefile that is the problem.   It is a standard header file that uses a something before it is declared.   That means either that your compiler (and associated headers and library) are not properly installed and configured (in which case, you need to install the compiler properly) or a bug in the compiler installation (unlikely, but you would need to report a flaw to the vendor).